# How to change emulator ram size?

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation

I am developing a WP8 app on a memory-constrained machine.

I can only run my app on the smaller-resolution emulator, but not the rest, because those require 1 GB of system ram.

How can I change the configuration for the emulators so that they use less memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no alternative but to add more RAM to your system (RAM is cheap these days).

For your information, here are the [requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) for the Windows Phone 8 SDK:

> - 6.5 GB of free hard disk space
> - 4 GB RAM
> - 64-bit (x64) CPU

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sTelfYz-oiQ98GSqPn-IBU7J0XTY24HocEU_mhxZFP0/edit?usp=sharing to edit static emulator RAM settings.